# Named Range not working in 'Case Is' Function

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

Below is the code that works perfectly okay...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     
Select Case Target.Address
            Case Is = ("$C$16")
            Select Case Target.Value
                Case "Please select from the dropdown list": Macro3
                Case "Yes - Standard form": Macro1
                Case "Yes - Bespoke": Macro2
                Case "No": Macro3
            End Select
    
    End Sub
```

As soon as I change the cell reference to the named range that is $C$16 in Excel (below), the VBA ignores the case without returning an error.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
Select Case Target.Address
            Case Is = Range("Answer")
            Select Case Target.Value
                Case "Please select from the dropdown list": Macro3
                Case "Yes - Standard form": Macro1
                Case "Yes - Bespoke": Macro2
                Case "No": Macro3
            End Select
    
    End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean `Range("Answer").Address` ? Use a breakpoint to check your variables as it runs.

Comment: There is one ´End Select´ missing and also change to ´Range("Answer").Address´ to compare equal things.

Comment: If the problem was a missing `End Select` then it wouldn't run at all. He just didn't include it in the question.